# Remove an imageview automatically after 5 seconds of no activity

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimageview

I have developed an application with one module that has one `UIImageView` on `self.view`. Over that `imageview`, the user can do a few operations that are working fine. My issue is that if the user is not interacting with that `imageview` then the `imageview` will have to be removed from `self.view` automatically after 5 seconds. How can I implement this? Do I need to use a timer or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use `NSTimer` for that , schedule a `NSTimer` for 5 sec like this -

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeImageView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

one more thing here that you need to schedule this `timer` when user `touch` the screen and if user `touch` the screen again then `invalidate` this timer and `reschedule` again.

Answer (score 3):

I subclassed UIWindow and in my CustomWindow class implemented the code (my time is 3 minutes of non-activiy then the timer "fires")

```
@implementation CustomWindow

// Extend method 
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [super sendEvent:event];

    // Only want to reset the timer on a Began touch, to reduce the number of timer resets.
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] > 0) 
    {
        // allTouches count only ever seems to be 1, so anyObject works here.
        UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
        if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan || phase == UITouchPhaseEnded) 
        {
            // spirko_log(@"touch  and class of touch - %@",  [((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).view  class]);
            [self resetIdleTimer:NO];
        }
    }
}


- (void) resetIdleTimer:(BOOL)force 
{
    // Don't bother resetting timer unless it's been at least 5 seconds since the last reset.
    // But we need to force a reset if the maxIdleTime value has been changed.
    NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    if (force || (now - lastTimerReset) > 5.0) 
    {
        // DebugLog(@"Reset idle timeout with value %f.", maxIdleTime);
        lastTimerReset = now;
        // Assume any time value less than one second is zero which means disable the timer.
        // Handle values > one second.
        if (maxIdleTime > 1.0) 
        {
            // If no timer yet, create one
            if (idleTimer == nil)
            {
                // Create a new timer and retain it.
                idleTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:maxIdleTime target:self selector:@selector(idleTimeExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
            }
            // Otherwise reset the existing timer's "fire date".
            else 
            {
              //  idleTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:maxIdleTime target:self selector:@selector(idleTimeExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];

                [idleTimer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:maxIdleTime]];
            }
        }
        // If maxIdleTime is zero (or < 1 second), disable any active timer.
        else {
            if (idleTimer)
            {
                [idleTimer invalidate];
                [idleTimer release];
                idleTimer = nil;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void) idleTimeExceeded 
{
  // hide your imageView or do whatever
}
```

Comment: This will need some changes for 5 seconds (you don't start a new timer if it is less than 5 seconds, and stop with 1 second left to go) but is the right approach.